# inequality similar to AM>GM

Tags: inequality

Is the inequality $$\frac{1}{n^2}(x-y)^2<xy$$ true in $[0,1]$ for some fixed positive integer $n$ and $x\neq y$?

I couldn't seem to get the answer, though I have a hunch that it is not so!

Any kind of help is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false.

Let $x=0.5$ and $y=0.1$. Then $$(x-y)^2=0.4^2=0.16$$ but $$xy=0.5\times0.1=0.05$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=3y$

$$(x-y)^2<xy \implies 4y^2<3y^2$$

Comment: Thanks, and I think multiplying the left side of the inequality by $\frac{1}{n}$ will not make it right unless $n\rightarrow\infty$? that is, $\frac{1}{n}(x-y)^2\not<xy$?

Comment: @markhaokip  Take $(x,y)=(1,0)$ see what happen ....whatver the value of n its false and $0<0$ is false for $n=\infty$

Comment: yw @markhaokip ........( I suppose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ )

Comment: yes @Isham $n\in\mathbb{N}$